# Install Sybase SQL Anywhere 11 as service

Tags: sqlanywhere

we are using Sybase SQL Anywhere 11. I am using command line to install/init database, `dbinit -dba %username%,%pwd% -p 4k %dbLocation%`, and start database server, `dbsrv11 %dbLocation%`, in a batch file.

What I really want is install my database as Windows service and can be start/running automatically when machine get reboot. But I want to keep using batch for easy intall/uninstall/change it.

Any Sybase expert here?

Comment: This is definitely a Server Fault question.

Answer (score 2):

found the answer: http://dcx.sybase.com/1100en/dbadmin_en11/dbsvc-service-dbutilities.html